# Showing Comma separated values from database in a textarea?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-5

I have really searched and searched and not found an answer. Given that one article can have multiple tags, I want to show the tags as comma separated values so that it looks like `Egypt, Sinai, Muslim Brotherhood`in a textarea when the article is edited. I'll post whatever code is needed if that will help in the answer.

My model is:

```
Partial Public Class be_Posts
        <Key>
        Public Property PostRowID As Integer
        Public Property BlogID As Guid
        Public Property PostID As Guid
        <StringLength(255)>
        Public Property Title As String
        Public Property Description As String
        <AllowHtml> Public Property PostContent As String
        Public Property DateCreated As Date?
        Public Property DateModified As Date?
        <StringLength(50)>
        Public Property Author As String
        Public Property IsPublished As Boolean?
        Public Property IsCommentEnabled As Boolean?
        Public Property Raters As Integer?
        Public Property Rating As Single?
        <StringLength(255)>
        Public Property Slug As String
        Public Property IsDeleted As Boolean
        Public Overridable Property be_PostTag As ICollection(Of be_PostTag)
        Public Overridable Property be_Categories As ICollection(Of be_Categories)

End Class
```

And the be_PostTag model

```
Partial Public Class be_PostTag
    <Key>
    Public Property PostTagID As Integer
    Public Property BlogID As Guid
    Public Property PostID As Guid
    <StringLength(50)>
    Public Property Tag As String
    Public Property be_Posts As ICollection(Of be_Posts)
End Class
```

I am working with an existing database and data and the models were generated from Code First From Database.

I realize I will need an EditorTemplate but beyond that I don't know what to do. How would I bind multiple values to a single textarea?

An image to show what i am talking about:

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  What, precisely, are you having trouble with?

Comment: How do I bind or show comma separate values from a database in a textarea? I am updating the post with an image to show what i am talking about.

Comment: What is the format/data-type of the source data?

Comment: I have added the be_PostTag model above as well as an image showing what I am trying to do.

Comment: And which part are you having trouble?  How to convert that data to the CSV format?  Or how to display the reformatted CSV string in the text box?  Or specifically how to use data-binding to bind to a reformatted value like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved:

Tossed this into an editor template:

```
    @modeltype IEnumerable(Of BetterBlog.Core.Entities.be_PostTag)

@code

    Dim sb As New StringBuilder

    For Each x In Model
        Dim tags = x.Tag & IIf(x.Equals(Model.Last), "", ", ")
        sb.Append(tags)

    Next

    @Html.TextArea("PostTags", sb.ToString, 10, 50, nothing)
End Code
```